# dlopen not finding library that ldconfig -p finds

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I'm trying to bind against the CUDA library shared.  As a quick verification I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;    
    handle = dlopen ("libcuda.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    dlclose(handle);
}
```

This fails with `libcuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

However, if I check ldconfig I get:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libcuda
        libcuda.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
        libcuda.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
        libcuda.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
```

So it seems that `libcuda.so` does exist and is seen by the system.  So why is `dlopen()` failing?

This is on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from your `ldconfig -p` that there is no symlink for `libcuda.so.1` x86_64, you just need to create it, try

```
sudo ln -svf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so{.1,}
```

it might be the case that you don't have the `-dev` package installed.

Or simply change

```
handle = dlopen ("libcuda.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

to

```
handle = dlopen ("libcuda.so.1", RTLD_LAZY);
```

but the first solution is better because when you link dynamically to `libcuda.so.1` with `-lcuda` the symlink migh be mandatory.

Comment: The symlink option worked, you are a life saver.   I wonder why Nvidia's own installation stuff for cuda does not do this.  Answer will be accepted in 7 minutes :)

Comment: Handling distribution specific settings is so hard... That's one of the things that make linux have less support from manufacturers I suppose.